# MVC 4 website compatibile with Phonegap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cordova

I'm developing an MVC website for mobile. The website should be compatible with Phonegap in the future, so I've done most of the client side logic using Web Api controllers and Ajax calls and my views are not linked to any Models. All my .cshtml files are now pure html/javascript codes.

But can I use MVC controllers to return empty views alone?

Will this work when I'm converting the code to phonegap?
because controllers usually return .cshtml files as views , but I will convert all cshtml to pure html in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with MVC in phonegap, phonegap uses Html/CSS for designing (front end) and JavaScript/JQuery/Ajax for logic (back-end).

Yes, you can return empty view but what about query and database related stuff, you have to use controller or model. This is all server-side stuff.

So answer is totally dependent on how is your Mobile App, for database connection you have to pass controller method's url in ajax call. For now, go ahead...